# Intersection of $2$ independent quadrics in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C_1,C_2$ be two linearly independent quadrics in $\mathbb P^3$ which are such that either one of them is irreducible or if both of them are not irreducible i.e $C_1=Z(pq), C_2 =Z(rs)$ then none of $Z(r),Z(s)$ is equal to $Z(p)$ or $Z(q)$(i.e they do not contain the same hyperplane). In this context my question is the following :

Can we say that in this situation $C_1,C_2$ do not share any common component(may not be irreducible)?

I am unable to see why not containing the same  hyperplane leads to not having any common component.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: If the quadric is irreducible, its only component is itself. If the quadric is reducible, its components are two planes. These are the only possibilities.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti, Does in general component means that we are looking for closed subset of same dimension, i.e in this case closed subsets of dimension $2$? Because otherwise we need to also ensure that they both  don't contain a common closed subset of dimension $1$. Please correct me if I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: In general a component of an algebraic set $V$ means an irreducible closed subset $W$ such that $W$ is not contained in the closure of $V \setminus W$. In general components can have different dimensions. However if $V$ is a hypersurface, then every component of $V$ is also a hypersurface.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti thanks. I hope that the statement regarding the dimension of components of hypersurface remains the same if we remove  irreducibility from the definition of "component".

Comment: If you remove "irreducible" from the definition of component, then every component is a finite union of irreducible components. The original statement says each irreducible component has the same dimension, so the same is true for any finite union of them.

Comment: Let me emphasise, though, that you should not remove "irreducible" from the definition of "component".